# Normalize pixel values between 0 and 1

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am looking to normalize the pixel values of an image to the range [0..1] using C++/OpenCV. However, when I do the normalization using either `image *= 1./255` or the normalize function the pixel values are rounded down to zero. I have tried setting the image to type `CV_32FC3`.

Below is the code I have:

```
  Mat image;
  image = imread(imageLoc, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);

  Mat tempImage;

  // (didn't work) tempImage *= 1./255;

  image.convertTo(tempImage, CV_32F, 3);
  normalize(image, tempImage, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);

  int r = 100;
  int c = 150;

  uchar* ptr = (uchar*)(tempImage.data + r * tempImage.step);
  Vec3f tempVals;
  tempVals.val[0] =  ptr[3*c+1];
  tempVals.val[1] =  ptr[3*c+2];
  tempVals.val[2] =  ptr[3*c+3];
  cout<<" temp image - "<< tempVals << endl;

  uchar* ptr2 = (uchar*)(image.data + r * image.step);
  Vec3f imVals;
  imVals.val[0] =  ptr2[3*c+1];
  imVals.val[1] =  ptr2[3*c+2];
  imVals.val[2] =  ptr2[3*c+3];
  cout<<" image - "<< imVals << endl;
```

This produces the following output in the console:

```
temp image - [0, 0, 0]
image - [90, 78, 60]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make `convertTo()` do the normalization for you:

```
image.convertTo(tempImage, CV_32FC3, 1.f/255);
```

You are passing `3` to `convertTo()`, presumably as channel-count, but that's not [the correct signature](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto).

Comment: This also produces an integer output

Comment: Why do you say that? Please try accessing the pixel using the `cv::Mat::at<float>(row,col)` method.

Comment: I was outputing some pixel values to the console to try and validate that the conversion was as I intended. Using the at<float>(r,c) method of accessing the values gave me the result I expected. Thanks.

Comment: Is the 255.5 a typo?

Comment: Yes - fixed. Changed to `1.f/255`

Answer (score 1):

I used the `normalize` function and it worked (Java):

```
Core.normalize(src,dst,0.0,1.0,Core.NORM_MINMAX,CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

You should use a 32F depth for your destination image. I believe the reason for this, is that since you need to get decimal values, you should use an a non-integer OpenCV data type. According to this [table](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15330998/20455198/9fedaa00-ae5e-11e6-8fab-1f15cddc4bba.JPG), the float types correspond to the 32F depth. I chose the number of channels to be 1 and it worked; `CV_32FC1`

Remember also that it's unlikely to spot any visual difference in the image.
Finally, since you probably have thousands of pixels in your image, your console might seem that it's printing only zeros. However due to the large amount of data, try to use `CTRL+F` to see what's going on. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain why "you should use the CV_32FC1 type".

Comment: why not float64?